# How To Open The Notifcations Settings Page on Android for Expo Managed App with SDK 47

Tags: android, expo

I am trying to implement a simple button to open the notification settings page for the app.
On previous expo SDKs, this code was used for opening the Android page:

```
const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel
    ? Constants.manifest.android.package // When published, considered as using standalone build
    : 'host.exp.exponent'

IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(IntentLauncher.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS, {
    data: 'package:' + pkg
})
```

But this now gives an error:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS dat=package: }
```

I've tried looking on Stackoverflow and Expo forums, but everything is using the old SDKs.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to do it using the `Linking` module.

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

const handleTurnNotificationsOn = async () => {
    await Linking.openSettings()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#sendintent-android

```
const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel
    ? Constants.manifest.android.package : 'host.exp.exponent'


Linking.sendIntent("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS", [
  {
    key: "android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE",
    value: pkg,
   },
]);
```